# Unable to set Plex posters metadata

Tags: python, plex

I'm working with the [AvalonRestAgent.bundle](https://github.com/joshuaavalon/AvalonRestAgent.bundle) and trying to modify it to set the poster of a media item. However, my attempts have been stalled.

**What I've done**

In my [utils.py](https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/8a89d3841b6e31100fcd0c4f4b0f6823#file-utils-py-L56) I created a method called set_metadata_posters which basically looks for the "posters" section of the [sample-response.json](https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/8a89d3841b6e31100fcd0c4f4b0f6823#file-sample-response-json-L62).I added a reference to it in [movie.py](https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/8a89d3841b6e31100fcd0c4f4b0f6823#file-movie-py-L5) and finally added a call to [set_metadata_posters](https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/8a89d3841b6e31100fcd0c4f4b0f6823#file-movie-py-L43) . You can see the entire [gist here](https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/8a89d3841b6e31100fcd0c4f4b0f6823)

**What Happens**

When I match the data, the logs show that it's retrieving the posters JSON and even logs then ["New poster added: {url}"](https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/8a89d3841b6e31100fcd0c4f4b0f6823#file-utils-py-L69). But no movie poster appears in Plex.

**Question**

I've looked at other Agents to try and determine what I'm doing differently, but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I blanked and forgot to call [valid_names.append(posterUrl)](https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/8a89d3841b6e31100fcd0c4f4b0f6823#file-utils-py-L67). Doh!